# Програмно заменить ImageView на CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox, imageview

Как заменить программно в ListView ImageView на CheckBox?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="end">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_str"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
```

При нажатии на пункт меню нужно, чтобы ImageView заменилась на CheckBox. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Правильный вариант**: Добавьте в вашу разметку скрытый CheckBox:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:paddingTop="18dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="end">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_str"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Затем в коде:

```
findViewById(R.id.image_str).setVisibility(View.GONE);
findViewById(R.id.check_box).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Можно `LinearLayout` поменять на `FrameLayout` и поставить `INVISIBLE` вместо `GONE`.

**Не очень правильный** и очень нудный вариант:

```
LinearLayout list = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.list));
list.removeAllViews()
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
// Здесь навешиваем на checkBox кучу параметров (паддинги и прочее)
list.addView(checkBox);
```

Comment: Сделал, как вы предложили, но "визуализируется" только один элемент в списке, самый первый. В остальных остается виден imageview

Comment: Если у вас свой кастомный адаптер то это несложная задача. В самом адаптере делаете item более сложным. Добавляете в него два boolean поля. Первое - isDeleteMode, второе - isSelected. В getView() метод адаптера во viewHolder добавляете поле для check_box и при isDeleteMode=true прячете изображение, показываете крыжик (и наоборот). При необходимости показать крыжики проходимся по всему списку адаптера, выставляем isDeleteMode=true и вызываем notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: И конечно внутри getView надо поставить на checkBox listener и менять isSelected в item чтобы знать что потом удалять...

Answer (score 2):

Можете для `ImageView` установить видимость `setVisibility(int)` на `GONE` и затем на ее место в `LinearLayout` добавить Ваш `CheckBox`.

Comment: сделал как вы предложили, однако я использую это в listview и это нужно для удаления, т.е .жму на значок корзины, все imageview должны заменится на чекбоксы, чтобы можно было выбрать какой элемент удалить. При попытке играть с видимостью заменяется лишь первый элемент списка, в остальных остается все тот же imageview

Comment: @denAbra, значит необходимо правильно это обрабатывать. При нажатии заменяйте во всех элементах. Почитайте как создавать свой адаптер http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter

Comment: так у меня и так свой адаптер, просто как понимаю тут надо (как?) получить список все элементов и заменить у всех, но как это сделать, я не знаю

Answer (score 1):

Программно поменять `ImageView` на `CheckBox` нельзя, Но вы можете управлять видимостью элементов.

1. Поместите в лайаут 2 Вью `ImageView` и `CheckBox`
2. В коде выставляйте для них видимость `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` чтобы показать нужный элемент и `setVisibility(View.GONE)` чтобы скрыть нужный элемент.

Comment: Вообще-то можно, никто не запрещает удалить из разметки `ImageView` и добавить на его место `CheckBox` программно, но это действительно не красиво получается. Так как вы предлагаете намного проще

Comment: Все зависит от того, кто как понял "заменить" =)

Comment: Ну, заменить лампочку означает *достать одну, и устаногвить другую*. Заменить колесо на машине значит *снять одно и поставить вместо него другое*. Тут, к сожалению, нет возможности для разного трактования. Слово *заменить* имеет всего одно вполне конкретное значение.

Comment: все это магия =)

Comment: сделал как вы предложили, однако я использую это в listview и это нужно для удаления, т.е .жму на значок корзины, все imageview должны заменится на чекбоксы, чтобы можно было выбрать какой элемент удалить. При попытке играть с видимостью заменяется лишь первый элемент списка, в остальных остается все тот же imageview

Answer (score 0):

Можете в вашем linearlayout в коде java сделать removeView(Ваш imageView). После создать checkBox и в linearlayout сделать addView(Ваш checkBox)